# Allow CORS in mkdocs local build (Failed to load <file:> Cross origin requests only supported for schemes http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https)

Tags: cors, documentation, mkdocs

I am running into an issue specifically with `font-awesome` and `search_index.json` while building mkdocs locally with `mkdocs build`. I understand the issue and why it isnt working, but i am trying to distribute my documentation locally instead of using a webserver which is why i must rely on `file://` instead of `http`. Is there a bypass for this?

I am getting the same result on latest Chrome and Firefox.

The actual issue is `Failed to load file:///Users/securisec/guide/site/search/search_index.json: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https`. which i understand. Wondering if there is a mkdocs config option to allow this when using file://. Based on their docs, i couldnt find someplace to set an additional header

Comment: Given it’s the browser that’s disallowing the cross-origin file: request, it doesn’t seem like there’s any way mkdocs could provide to override that blocking.

Answer (score 1):

No, MkDocs does not and can not provide a workaround for this. The limitation is enforced by the browser. The only workaround would be to disable your browser's security settings, which is **not** recommended.

This was the issue raised in [#871](https://github.com/mkdocs/mkdocs/issues/871) and the conclusion was:

> I took another look at this. Even if we pre-generate the index, that index is still a JSON file which is not accessible with the `file://` scheme.
>
> Search is now in a plugin. If you really need this, then you can create your own plugin which uses some other search implementation.